# How do I remove a node in a BST without duplicating nodes?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

My code is below. I'm having trouble with the deletion method, I can not delete a node in the binary search tree and replace it without creating two of the replacement nodes... How can I fix this?

```
public class BSTMain {
public static void DeleteValue(int num, BSTNode root){
    BSTNode cursor = root;
    while(true){ //move cursor
        while(cursor.getLeft()!=null && num<cursor.getData()){
            //move cursor
            cursor = cursor.getLeft();
        }
        while(cursor.getRight()!=null && num>cursor.getData()){
            //move cursor
            cursor = cursor.getRight();
        }
        if(cursor.getData() == num || (cursor.getLeft()==null && num<cursor.getData()) || (cursor.getRight()==null && num>cursor.getData())) //check for placing cases 
            break; //time to delete node in the tree
    }
    if(cursor.getData()==num){//delete node
        if(cursor.getLeft()!=null){ //if left exists
            BSTNode cursor2 = cursor.getLeft();
            while(cursor2.getRight()!=null){ //get rightmost of left to replace
                cursor2 = cursor2.getRight();
            }
            cursor.setData(cursor2.getData()); //replace cursor
            if(cursor2.getLeft()!=null)
                cursor2.getLeft().root = cursor2.root; //Replace cursor2
            cursor2.root.setRight(cursor2.getLeft());
        } else if(cursor.getRight()!=null){ //if no left but right
            BSTNode cursor2 = cursor.getRight(); 
            while(cursor2.getLeft()!=null){ //get leftmost of right
                cursor2 = cursor2.getLeft();
            }
            cursor.setData(cursor2.getData()); //replace cursor
            if(cursor2.getRight()!=null)
                cursor2.getRight().root = cursor2.root; //Replace cursor2
            cursor2.root.setLeft(cursor2.getRight());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Node " + num + " does not exist!");
        }
    }
    else System.out.println(num + " does not exist in Binary Search Tree!");
}
}
```

Some Output:

In Order: 19 20   21  22  23  23  45 

Command: D 19

After Deletion: 20 20   21  22  23  23  45 
Command: D 20
After Deletion: 20 20   21  22  23  23  45 
Command: D 21
After Deletion: 20  20  22  23  23  45 
Command: D 22
After Deletion: 20  20  20 20   23  23  45 
Command: D 23
After Deletion: 20  20  20 20   23  23 20  20  20 20    45 
Command: D 45
After Deletion: 20  20  20  23  23 20  20  20   20 
Command: D 20
After Deletion: 20  20  20  23  23 20  20   20 
Command: D 20
After Deletion: 20  20  20  23  23 20   20 
Command: D 20
After Deletion: 20  20  20  23  23  20 
Command: D 20
After Deletion: 20  20  20  23  23  23 20  20  20  23  
Command: D 23
After Deletion: 20  20  20  23  23  23 20  20  20  23  
Command: E

Comment: What do you mean by `I can not delete a node in the binary search tree and replace it without creating two of the replacement nodes`? What would be the correct behavior?

Comment: The correct behaviour would be to replace the node entirely, without creating an extra node. In other words, moving the node - cursor2 - to the position of cursor.

Comment: It looks like you're copying the data from the replacement node over to the deleted node, and failing to detach the replacement node.

Comment: assuming `root` is actually the parent - `cursor2.root.setRight(null)` (or `setLeft`, depending on which child it is...)